# NoSuchMethodError SmsRetrieverClient

Tags: android

I have received the following error after upgrading dependencies

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbel;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi' appears in /data/app/com.gifme-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes30.dex)
                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetrieverClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzash.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever.getClient(Unknown Source)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.createSmsToken(PhoneLoginController.java:250)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.logIn(PhoneLoginController.java:188)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.LoginManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(LoginManager.java:372)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.logInWithPhoneNumber(AccountKitController.java:627)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneLoginFlowManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(PhoneLoginFlowManager.java:57)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ActivityPhoneHandler.onPhoneLoginComplete(ActivityPhoneHandler.java:189)
                                        at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity$1.onReceive(AccountKitActivity.java:176)
                                        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:308)
                                        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
                                        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:118)
                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

27420

I am using Facebook AccountKit and clicking on "NEXT" button to check the sms verification crashes the app.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Add the dependency

`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.2"`

Comment: you can use updated version:                                                                    
**implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0"** Please find the release notes here [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem. The answer of Rachit Mishra worked for me. Add the dependency.

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.2"
```

Seems that we have to explicitly mention auth api of google as well.